# How to get the subdomain of a URL using PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, url, subdomain

I have some URLs like these:

```
1.  https://www.example.com/classname/method/arg      // {nothing}
2.  http://www.example.com/classname/method/arg       // {nothing}
3.  https://example.com/classname/method/arg          // {nothing}
4.  http://example.com/classname/method/arg           // {nothing}
5.  www.example.com/classname/method/arg              // {nothing}
6.  example.com/classname/method/arg                  // {nothing}
7.  sub.example.com/classname/method/arg              // sub
8.  www.sub.example.com/classname/method/arg          // sub
9.  http://sub.example.com/classname/method/arg       // sub
10. https://sub.example.com/classname/method/arg      // sub
11. http://www.sub.example.com/classname/method/arg   // sub
12. https://www.sub.example.com/classname/method/arg  // sub

// $url ^                                             // What I want ^
```

Now, as you see I want to get sobdomain of those URLs. How?

---

I have two approaches, but none of them doesn't work for all URLs as well:

**First:** *(this just work for `7`)*

```
echo array_shift((explode(".",$url)));
```

**Second:** *(It's better a bit)*

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
echo $host[0];
```

Comment: your definition of subdomain is wrong

Comment: @Dagon Actually I'm trying to create an API for my website. Now I want to detect it by the word of `api` in the URL as subdomain (for e.g. `http://api.example.com`). Also I want to it works for every kind of URLs.

Comment: It would be costly (in computational terms) to check for the current subdomain at each request just to see if it's an API request. You're way better just using Apache (or whatever server) virtual DNS to have api.example.com open a specific file that specifically handles API requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$url = 'http://sub.example.com/classname/method/arg';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;
```

**For multiple subdomains you should do like this**

```
$url = 'http://en.sub.example.com/classname/method/arg';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomains = array_slice($host, 0, count($host) - 2 );
print_r($subdomains);
```

Comment: `if(in_array('api',$host)){//api found}`

Comment: @Dagon Thanks. Seems good. Just one thing. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` works for `https`?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']: Returns the Host header from the current request. It works.

Answer (score 1):

**I am going to leave this here...**

Using @TwoStraws' idea, I created a function which will provide the Sub Domain, Base Domain, and TLD Domain parts from a given URL, using data.iana.org's up to date TLD list.

```
function GetDomainParts($URL,$TLDs_List = 'http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt') {
    // Get a list of all top level domains
    $TLDs = explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents($TLDs_List));
    unset($TLDs[0]); array_values($TLDs);

    // And since that list has all the country codes too, lets assume all 2 letter domains are country codes, and get that list too
    $CC_TLDs = [];
    foreach($TLDs as $TLD) {
        if(strlen($TLD) == 2) {
            $CC_TLDs[] = $TLD;
        }
    }

    // Now lets take our URL and remove some things
    $ParsedUrl = parse_url($URL);
    $Host = explode('.', $ParsedUrl['host']);

    // If we cant find it, we return false...
    $BaseDomain = false;
    $TLDDomain = false;

    // And look at the last 2 items in the Host array, these will be our TLD's (possibly)
    $N_Minus_1 = strtoupper(isset($Host[count($Host)-1])?$Host[count($Host)-1]:null);
    $N_Minus_2 = strtoupper(isset($Host[count($Host)-2])?$Host[count($Host)-2]:null);

    // This has a potential of being our base domain, but may not be there
    $N_Minus_3 = strtoupper(isset($Host[count($Host)-3])?$Host[count($Host)-3]:null);


    // We first check our N Minus 1 against our list of Country Code TLDs
    if(in_array($N_Minus_1,$CC_TLDs)) {
        // If N Minus 1 is in the Country Code, We can check our N Minus 2 and see if it is in the TLDs array
        if(in_array($N_Minus_2,$TLDs)) {
            // If N Minus 2 is in the list of TLDs, we make the assumption that this is part of the TLD, making N Minus 3 our Base Domain
            $BaseDomain = $N_Minus_3;
            $TLDDomain = $N_Minus_2.'.'.$N_Minus_1;

            // We unset the parts that are used, the rest is our sub domain
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            $SubDomain = implode('.',$Host);
        } else {
            // If N Minus 2 is NOT in the list of TLDs, we make the assumption that this is our Base Domain
            $BaseDomain = $N_Minus_2;
            $TLDDomain = $N_Minus_1;

            // We unset the parts that are used, the rest is our sub domain
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            $SubDomain = implode('.',$Host);
        }
    } else {
        // If N Minus 1 is NOT in the Country Codes, we can assume it is the TLD, lets check it against the TLDs to make sure
        if(in_array($N_Minus_1,$TLDs)) {
            // If N Minus 1 Is in our List of TLDs, we can assume we found our TLD, so N Minus 2 must be our Base Domain
            $BaseDomain = $N_Minus_2;
            $TLDDomain = $N_Minus_1;

            // We unset the parts that are used, the rest is our sub domain
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            $SubDomain = implode('.',$Host);
        } else {
            // If N Minus 1 is NOT in our list of TLDs it is either a new TLD unheard of by iana.org, or does not exist, lets make the assumption that it is the tld
            $BaseDomain = $N_Minus_2;
            $TLDDomain = $N_Minus_1;

            // We unset the parts that are used, the rest is our sub domain
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            unset($Host[count($Host)-1]);
            $SubDomain = implode('.',$Host);

            // Not sure if it is needed, but at this point we can swap the checks, checking minus 2 as the country code and minus 1 as the TLD, 
            // but I am not sure this is ever a real world scenerio, and am unable to find any proof to support this theory
        }

    }

    // Return our URL Parts ( DISCLAIMER: Note that this will not solve every URL, such as WWW.AFAMILYCOMPANY.CO, 
    // because both AFAMILYCOMPANY and CO are TLDs one being a TLD and the other being a Country Code, Leaving "WWW" as the Base Domain.
    // I use this functionality to auto-populate a user changeable setting, just in case my assumption is wrong the user can fix it.
    // One should not assume this will work 100% of the time! )
    return [strtolower($SubDomain),strtolower($BaseDomain),strtolower($TLDDomain)];
}
```

**PLEASE READ THE DISCLAIMER...**

Note that this will not solve every URL, such as WWW.AFAMILYCOMPANY.CO, because both AFAMILYCOMPANY and CO are TLDs one being a TLD and the other being a Country Code, Leaving "WWW" as the Base Domain. I use this functionality to auto-populate a user changeable setting, just in case my assumption is wrong the user can fix it. One should not assume this will work 100% of the time!

Further note that, http://whois.domaintools.com/afamilycompany.co is listed as a "Restricted and Reserved Names" domain. If the internet is doing things right, then these type of domains should never be in production anyway, and therefor this function is safe.

A simple way to check if this functionality will work on your domain(s) for sure, is to go to http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt press Ctrl+F and check if the domain is in the list, if it is, this function will fail, if it is not, this function will work 100% of the time. I realize this is only a step in the right direction, so if anyone else can add onto the idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using `explode()`, but you should probably also use the `parse_url()` function to get the domain from the URL: [see here for docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). TL;DR: Give it a URL as its only parameter, and get back an array of all the parts of the URL broken up individually.

That being said, a bigger problem is how you distinguish between subdomain.somesite.com and somesite.co.uk - the first one clearly has a subdomain, but the second one does not. I'm afraid I have no smart solutions to offer for that other than comparing against a list of top-level domains.

Comment: Hello @TwoStraws, did you by chance create the code you described here? I am having a similar issue where I need to be able to distinguish between this-being.a-subdomain.at-base-domain.com and the alternative this-being.a-subdomain.at-base-domain.co.uk, it sounds like your solution of comparing the tld's would work, if you can provide some working code here I would consider this a more helpful answer. Either way, thanks for the thought.